# Use of where constraint in laravel eloquent ORM

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I understood that Laravel's Eloquent ORM queries generally had the structure

1. The model
2. Query Constraints
3. Fetch methods.

However, can someone tell me what this code would do?

```
$user = User::where('username', '=', $username)->where('active', '=', 1);
```

It seems to have 2 constraints, but no fetch method, 
for example I would expect the query to have
`->first()` or
`->update(array('key' => 'value')` or
`->delete()`
 or similar on the end?

Comment: It will build the query as a query object in $user, but won't execute the query. Somewhere else in the code, there's likely to be a call like $user->find() to actually execute the query

Comment: nice one. thats exactly what it does. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The code only sets up the query with the two mentioned where clauses. This is useful when you want to add clauses depending on different conditions:

```
$user = User::where('username', '=', $username)
            ->where('active', '=', 1);

if ($filterByAge) {
    $user->where('age', '>', $age);
}

if ($filterByHeight) {
    $user->where('height', '>', $height);
}

return $user->get();
```

Or when you're applying them from, let's say, an array:

```
$wheres = [
    'username' => 'Raphael',
    'active'   => true,
    'height'   => '173'
];

$user = User::query();

foreach ($wheres as $field => $value) {
    $user->where($field, '=', $value);
}

return $user->get();
```

Comment: thats interesting, thanks. Say you set up the query using the conditional or array statements you described. Does the model/table +  where constraints you setup still persist in the $user object even after the query is executed? e.g. once the foreach has completed could you say  `if($user->count()) { return $user->get(); } ` ?